# Source for upcoming rule changes

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What is the primary source for upcoming rule changes? Who breaks the official news?

I know that these changes are made publicly available before they actually take effect. For example, I found out about the updated "2014 Core Set Legend rule" via a video from The Judge's Corner on Youtube. I have also discovered upcoming rules changes through StarCityGames news articles. Both of these outlets are probably secondary sources.

Comment: I don't know if there's something earlier (I'm not sure when the things you mention were published) but are you aware of the update bulletins Wizards posts on their site, e.g. http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/khans-tarkir-update-bulletin-2014-09-17 for Khans?

Comment: Or if you know how to find that video and compare dates, here's M14: http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/Magazine/Article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/255c

Comment: @Jefromi For what it's worth, the [Judge's Corner video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7EqU4Y_hxI&list=PLvxA59vwMksqKGn639LMf6nZ9xy4yw9jh&index=37) was published on June 10, 2013. That's actually *before* the Wizards article date of July 12, 2013. But I've already got one answer claiming that the Wizards news bulletins are the primary source.

Comment: Well, the update bulletins specifically look official so it seemed the important one to check if it was the first. But wow, a month before - I wonder if there are leaks or secret judge newsletters?

Comment: @Jefromi It's possible that the primary source is not the first available source due to leaks. That would be disappointing, because this site isn't a good fit for "What is the best place to find leaks?" I guess I need to ask that question on a more "gossipy" site.

Comment: Looks like Judge's Corner is from Gathering Magic, and those folks appear to have "spoilers" from Fate Reforged already, so... I wouldn't be totally surprised.

Comment: The spoilers from Fate Restored are actually official,  they were released at some con or another a while back

Comment: @diego Ah, I see - I didn't actually scroll enough on that page to see there were only three cards (from PAX Australia, looks like), not some awful leaked spoilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official announcement of any rules changes is made in an article on Wizards' [Magic site](https://web.archive.org/web/20220621133226/https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles). This article is generally posted the week of a set's pre-release event ([Khans of Tarkit Update Bulletin](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/khans-tarkir-update-bulletin-2014-09-17)), or in the case of products that do not have pre-releases like the Commander 2014 decks the set's release date. Occasionally they are a little late for example the [Commander 2014 Release Notes](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/release-notes-2014-11-10) were not posted until the week after the decks released.

Wizards also usually release an article when previews start detailing all of the mechanics that will be in the set, for example [Mechanics of Khans of Tarkir](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/mechanics-khans-tarkir). The difference between these articles is that the Mechanics of ______ articles do not have any actual rules text, they just describe how the mechanics work, and they only contain information on one set.

The Update Bulletin on the other hand has the actual text for the mechanics that will be in the Comprehensive Rules, it also contains any other updates and changes they are making to other rules (for example they recently changed Convoke and Delve in the Magic 2014 Update Bulletin even though Delve wasn't in the set at all). It also contains any changes to the Oracle text of cards.

For your Judge Cast video Wizards actually posted an [article](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/making-magic/magic-2014-core-set-rules-preview-2013-05-23) about a month prior to the video listing some of the changes they were planning on making. This doesn't happen very often, but they do it occasionally for bigger changes that might change how people play the game. So for that change there was a big change to how the Legend Rule and Planeswalker Uniqueness Rules worked and releasing the news early allowed people to prepare for the changes, so for example if you played Commander and your decks way of dealing with opposing commanders was to clone them that would no longer work so you would have to redo a large portion of your deck and telling everyone there would be changes coming would allow you to get your deck ready for when they did.

So while they occasionally post additional articles on their site, the primary source for any rules information is usually either the Mechanics of ______ and the ______ Update Bulletin articles.

Anything outside of an official Wizards source is a secondary source probably getting their information from either of these two sources, or statements by Wizards employees on social media. On rare occasions there might be leaks of upcoming rules that other sites report on before it is officially posted on Magic's site I would not consider them to be a primary source, since they are still getting their information from Wizards it just isn't published yet.

Comment: Did you see the example here? Judge's Corner posted a video about details of the rules update a month before the update bulletin was posted.

Comment: It looks like Wizard's posted http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/2012 before that video

Comment: Your link is broken, but the [Magic 2014 Update Bulletin](http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/Magazine/Article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/255c) says July 12, 2013, while the Judge's Corner video was June 10 - see the comments on the question. Did you find a different M14 rules post?

Comment: Yeah it was posted May 23rd by Matt Tabak      http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/248e

Comment: That seems worth adding into your answer - I know they may not do that for every rules update, but it certainly explains the Judge's Corner video being so early. Not sure about the StarCityGames ones, since the OP didn't mention what set it was.

Comment: I  can do that when I get home so I'm not on my phone, when I wrote my answer the exact video hadn't been posted